# D CTFE and GPU Code Generation

Tags: glsl, opencl, d, mixins, ctfe

Could D's Mixins be used to map linear algebra operations to **either/both** CPU code and OpenCL or GPU vertex shader functions such as GLSL? This would be a real killer application for D and better bridge logic targeted for both CPU and GPU execution. Compare this with [glm](http://glm.g-truc.net/) and D's [gl3n](http://dav1dde.github.com/gl3n/) which is only compile fixed-size linear algebra to CPU-code.

[VexCL](http://ddemidov.github.com/vexcl/) is a proof of concept for this using OpenCL and C++11 (GCC 4.6 or later) by *completely* abstracting away backend-dependent (CPU/GPU) implementation details about memory allocations and code execution somewhat similar to C++ AMP. So things can only get better in D right? Can mixins completely replace the use of C++ expression templates used in VexCL? [Here's a nice  tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415058/VexCL-Vector-expression-template-library-for-OpenC) on its use.

CTFE may also play a role here in this discussion.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, definitely. In fact it should be quite straightforward. I did a proof-of-concept of this sort of thing back in 2007 (see my presentation at the first D conference).
Hardly anything worked in CTFE in those days, but it was still an order of magnitude easier than doing the equivalent thing in C++.

The desire to do this sort of thing was part of the motivation for development of template value parameters, CTFE, and SIMD operations.

Comment: Do you have any documents or code to refer to, either of your own or from others?

Comment: The code I wrote at the time is probably still on dsource.org in the MathExtra project. But, as I said, the compiler has improved so much in the past 5 years that my code is all hopelessly obsolete. Back then, you couldn't even use structs at compile time; now you can even throw exceptions and use pointers!
The compile-time regex implementation in Phobos is a good example of more recent code.